# Null value obtained in Flutter from JSON back-end code?

Tags: json, flutter, dart, null, flutter-futurebuilder

I'm currently coding a project with front-end in Flutter+Dart, and back-end in JSON. I am trying to pull profile data entered by the user to display in the settings via a FutureBuilder, but every time even though I can view the profile data in the log, it keeps returning as a null value in Flutter. Any suggestions ? Thanks :)

```
import 'package:json_annotation/json_annotation.dart';
part 'profile_model.g.dart';

@JsonSerializable(explicitToJson: true)
class ProfileModel {
  String? firstname;
  String? lastname;
  String? birthday;
  String? weight;
  ProfileModel({this.firstname, this.lastname, this.birthday, this.weight});

  factory ProfileModel.fromJson(Map<String,dynamic> json) => _$ProfileModelFromJson(json);

  Map<String,dynamic> toJson() => _$ProfileModelToJson(this);
}
```

```
class SettingsProfile extends StatefulWidget {
  const SettingsProfile({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  _SettingsProfileState createState() => _SettingsProfileState();}

class _SettingsProfileState extends State<SettingsProfile> {
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  final networkHandler = NetworkHandler();
  bool circular = true;

  Widget page = CircularProgressIndicator();

  @override
  void initState() {super.initState(); checkProfile();}

  void checkProfile() async {
    var response = await networkHandler.get('/profile/checkProfile');
    if (response['status'] == true) {setState(() {page = showProfile();});}
    else {setState(() {page = emptyProfile();});}}

  TextEditingController firstnameController = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController lastnameController = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController birthdayController = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController weightController = TextEditingController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Mon profil')),
      body: page,);}

    Future<ProfileModel> _loadProfileModel() async {
      var response = await networkHandler.get("/profile/getData");
      setState(() {ProfileModel profileModel = ProfileModel.fromJson(response["data"]);});
      return response;}

  Widget showProfile() {

    return FutureBuilder<ProfileModel>(
      future: _loadProfileModel(),
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {

        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
          if (snapshot.data == null) {
            return Text('no data');
          } else {
            print((snapshot.data()! as Map<String, dynamic>)['firstname'] as String);
            return Text('data present');
          }
        } else if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
          return Text('Error'); // error
        } else {
          return CircularProgressIndicator(); // loading
        }
      }
    );

    /*
    return Scaffold(
        body: FutureBuilder(
          future: _loadProfileModel(),
          builder: (context, data) {
            if (data.hasError) {
              return Center(child: Text("${data.error}"));
            } else if (data.hasData) {
                    return Card(
                      elevation: 5,
                      margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10, vertical: 6),
                      child: Container(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
                        child: Row(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                          children: [

                            Expanded(
                                child: Container(
                                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 8),
                                  child: Column(
                                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                    children: [
                                      Padding(
                                        padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 8, right: 8),
                                        child: Text(
                                          profileModel.firstname.toString(),
                                          style: TextStyle(
                                              fontSize: 16,
                                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                      Padding(
                                        padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 8, right: 8),
                                        child: Text(profileModel.lastname.toString()),
                                      )
                                    ],
                                  ),
                                ))
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    );

            } else {
              return Center(
                child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
              );
            }
          },
        )
    );
     */


    /*
    void fetchData() async {
      var response = await networkHandler.get("/profile/getData");
      setState(() {
        ProfileModel profileModel = ProfileModel.fromJson(response["data"]);
      });
    }
    fetchData();
    return Text(profileModel.firstname.toUpperCase());
     */
  }

  Widget emptyProfile() {
    // GOOD CODE
  }
}
```

Edit : added this next block of code to simplify the one right above

```
class _SettingsProfileState extends State<SettingsProfile> {
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  final networkHandler = NetworkHandler();
  ProfileModel profileModel = ProfileModel();
  bool circular = true;

  TextEditingController firstnameController = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController lastnameController = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController birthdayController = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController weightController = TextEditingController();

  Widget page = CircularProgressIndicator();

  @override
  void initState() {super.initState(); checkProfile(); fetchData();}

  void checkProfile() async {
    var response = await networkHandler.get('/profile/checkProfile');
    if (response['status'] == true) {setState(() {
      page = showProfile();
    });}
    else {setState(() {page = emptyProfile();});}}

  void fetchData() async {
    var foundDetails = await networkHandler.get("/profile/getData");
    setState(() {
      ProfileModel profileModel = ProfileModel.fromJson(foundDetails);
      circular = false;});}

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Mon profil')),
      body: page,);}

  Widget showProfile() {
    return Container(
      child: Text(
        profileModel.weight.toString(),
        style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 18, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),),);}
```

Comment: What is the response of your backend?

Comment: `[log] {"status":true}
[log] {"_id":"62b60b106bccb799436fa5bc","email":"alex@gmail.com","firstname":"john","lastname":"smith","birthday":"january","weight":"80","__v":0}`

Comment: where the variable profilemodel is declared?

Comment: I call it once initially like this `ProfileModel profileModel = ProfileModel();` which you can see in the very beginning of the third block of code, then I call it again in `void fetchData()` and then again in `Widget showProfile()` but I don't know if they're linked with each other or if the void function value is being left out, which is the reason for the null value, just based on the initial declaration of profileModel ? Just saw your suggestion, will try it out, thanks

Comment: Check for errors: snapshot.hasError and snapshot.error contains a actual error.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
void fetchData() async {
var foundDetails = await networkHandler.get("/profile/getData");
setState(() {
  /*ProfileModel*/ profileModel = ProfileModel.fromJson(foundDetails);
  circular = false;});}
```

Comment: Unfortunately I receive the same error as before ...

Comment: can you print foundDetails in the method fetchData?

Answer (score 0):

```
Future<ProfileModel> _loadProfileModel() async {
  var response = await networkHandler.get("/profile/getData");
  setState(() {ProfileModel profileModel = ProfileModel.fromJson(response["data"]);});
  return response;}
```

What does this method do? it is supposed to return a `ProfileModel` but instead, it returns the API response, plus, your are declaring a variable inside the `setState`, this means that it's scope is only that `setState` method.
your method should be:

```
Future<ProfileModel> _loadProfileModel() async {
    var response = await networkHandler.get("/profile/getData");
    return ProfileModel.fromJson(response["data"]);
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately I am getting this as an error now : `The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown building FutureBuilder<ProfileModel>(dirty, state: _FutureBuilderState<ProfileModel>#99002):
Class 'ProfileModel' has no instance method 'call'.
Receiver: Instance of 'ProfileModel'
Tried calling: call()`